# Переполнение дискового пространства

Tags: windows, администрирование

Проблема: очень быстро заполняется мусором каталог

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5`

Окружение: 
Windows 7, Интернет броузер - Google Chrome

Здесь https://blog.paessler.com/how-to-get-rid-of-huge-default-userlocal-settingstemporary-internet-filescontentie5-folders расписывается причина и дается метод решения в стиле "лом в подворотне":

```
del \q\s "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\*"
```

Однако это борьба с уже случившимися последствиями. Очень хотелось бы устранить источник проблемы. Никаких "Full Page Sensors" я нигде не устанавливал. Используется "Google Chrome" в обычной конфигурации. MicroSoft Internet Explorer нигде явно не используется.

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь знает волшебную конфигурацию флажков, управляющую этим процессом, и устраняющую источник проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках "Панель управления/Свойства браузера" установите максимальный размер кешируемой информации или отключите кеширование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Оно!  Как просто, если знаешь :).